# How to get all resultset values from a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to select multiple columns from a table which have multiple result set value. I found some question already been answered, but couldn't find a specific one that would help me in my condition.

I tried this but still no luck:

```
String dboutp = "";
try {
    DBConnect Database = new DBConnect();
    Connection con = Database.getcon();
    String query="SELECT ITEM, PHP FROM table WHERE name=?";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    int columnCount = 0;
    Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; ++i) {
        row[i - 1] = rs.getString(i); // Or even rs.getObject()
        System.out.println(row[i-1]);
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = null;
    model.addRow(row);
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also tried:

```
String dboutp = "";
try {
    DBConnect Database = new DBConnect();
    Connection con = Database.getcon();
    String query="SELECT ITEM, PHP FROM table WHERE name=?";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    int i=1;
    while(rs.next()){
        dboutp=dboutp+","+rs.getString(i);
        i++;
    }
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At first method in line `model.addRow(row)` I'm getting an exception saying `java.lang.NullPointerException`, and in second method this exception occurs: `java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1`.

I would really appreciate if someone tell me what is the appropriate way of accessing multiple result set values including multiple column values.

Comment: You might want to read a basic JDBC tutorial, for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html (and the rest of that JDBC tutorial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you are conflating "rows" in the resultset, and "columns" in the row.

Loop through the rows. And for each row, get the values of the columns.

To get something working, start with something simple. You can use a variable to count the number of rows fetched. Just don't confuse the number of rows you've fetched with the number of columns in the row.

```
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    int rn = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
       rn++;
       String item = rs.getString(1);
       String php  = rs.getString(2);

       System.out.println(" rn=" + rn + " item=" + item + " php=" + php);

    }
    System.out.println(" fetched total of " + rn + " rows");
```